# Remote validation with SimpleMembership in MVC4 - Doesnt hit controller method

Tags: validation, jquery, simplemembership

I am trying to use Remote Validation on the UserName proerty, on the Register page, so the user gets a notice if the user name is already taken.  It worked before I added the SimpleMembership stuff.

After adding simlplemembership, it stopped working, returned an error, something about all the simplemembership tables not having PKs.  I researched and found a somewhat built-in way to do the remote validation.

Now I get no errors, and I can see in the network tab of the google developer tools, that the ajax call is being made to the correct controller, but I put a breakpoint in the controller method, and it does not get hit.  So not sure what to do.  Here is how I am setup:

The model with the Remote attribute attached.:

```
    [Required]
    [Remote("VerifyUserExists", "Account")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

The controller method thats does not get hit:

```
    public JsonResult VerifyUserExists(string username)
    {
        var user = Membership.GetUser(username);

        if (user != null)
        {
            return Json(ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName),
                            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

and validation is enabled in the web config;

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Any ideas what i am missing?  Again, this all worked before I added in the simplemembership stuff.

Comment: You indicate that the ajax call is being made by looking at google tools.  What HTTP status code is being returned in the response? If you cannot tell from google tools try using Fiddler.

Comment: HTTP status code of 302 is a redirect, which usually occurs when there is a server error. Check server logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: If I am running it on my box using vs2012, how do i check server logs?

Comment: @Kevin - Thank you. I found the logs and figured out that the ajax call couldn't hit the VerifyUser method because I forgot to decorate it with [AllowAnnonymous].  So it was hitting, deciding it was not authorized, then redirecting to the login method.  Got her fixed now.  Go ahead and answer so I can give you a tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the HTTP status code being returned in the response.  If the cannot tell what the status code is from Google Tools use Fiddler.  If the status code is 302 then the server is sending a redirect, which usually occurs when there is a server error. Check the server logs to see if there are any errors to determine what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

On the GET: /Account/VerifyUserExists
Add

[AllowAnonymous]

Since you switched to the SimpleMemberShip stuff, the default [Authorize] annonation is set. So for public GET's you should explicitly set the [AllowAnonymous]